# Unable to find the locator with Link Text test case getting failed

Tags: selenium, xpath

I am not able find the locator with anchor tag. Using xpath doesn't give the result.

Here is the HTML code :

```
<a id="sme1" class="item" href="/website-url" onclick="swapClasses('sme1')" 
target="main" style="background-color: 
transparent;">Mailboxes</a>
```

**Selenium code :**

```java
private static final String baseURL = "http://10.112.75.248/";
    private static final String adminURL = baseURL + "manager/";
    private static String username = "admin";
    private static String password = "default";

    WebDriver driver ;
    SearchElement searchEl;

@BeforeTest
    public void setBaseURL(){
        driver = new FirefoxDriver();
        driver.get(adminURL);
        searchEl = new SearchElement();
    }

@Test(priority=0)
  public void verifyLoginSuccessFull() {
      searchEl.getElementsByXpath(driver, "//input[@name='username']").sendKeys(username);
      searchEl.getElementsByXpath(driver, "//input[@name='password']").sendKeys(password);
      searchEl.getElementsByXpath(driver, "//input[@name='submit']").submit();
      String expected = "Selenium Home Page";
      Assert.assertEquals(driver.getTitle(), expected);
  }

@Test(priority=1)
  public void addMailbox(){

      //WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 1000);
      //wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//a[text()='Mailboxes']")));
      //driver.findElement(By.id("smel")).click();
      searchEl.getElementsByLinkText(driver, "//a[text()='Mailboxes']").click(); //This line of code not fetching the locator.


  }
```

**SearchElement class used as a controller :**

```java
public class SearchElement {



    public WebElement getElementsByXpath(WebDriver driver,String locator){

        WebElement el = driver.findElement(By.xpath(locator));

        return el;

    }

    public WebElement getElementsByLinkText(WebDriver driver,String locator){

        WebElement el = driver.findElement(By.linkText(locator));

        return el;

    }

}
```

Actual Error :

> Unable to locate element: {"method":"link
>   text","selector":"//a[text()='Mailboxes']"}

**Note :** The URL is different when the user logs in and when the user is presented the login page. I dont know it might be a problem.

Please help in advance.

Comment: Is there anyone who can answer me...

Comment: where does `text()='Mailboxes` exists in the html?

Comment: Sorry updating the question. See the html code now...

Comment: A new update .. Even selenium IDE locates the element but executing the test case it also fails..

Answer (score 1):

`By.linkText()` method expects *link text* as parameter, but in that code you're passing *XPath string*. Try to pass the *link text* instead :

```java
searchEl.getElementsByLinkText(driver, "Mailboxes").click();
```

Comment: Still the same error or without any error message now?

Comment: Error shown at console : Caused by: org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: Unable to locate element: {"method":"link text","selector":"Mailboxes"}

Comment: yes check the code : 
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 5);
   wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.linkText("Mailboxes")));
   searchEl.getElementsByLinkText(driver, "Mailboxes").click();

Comment: one more thing to tell you, URL is getting changed from Login page to Login Successfull page. Does it effect the test case also.

Answer (score 0):

try this.

```
 //a[.='Mailboxes']
```

This is a text base search and "." inside the xpath navigates you to the parent

Comment: Have you made sure this is not a wait issue?

Comment: the page takes at least 4-5 seconds to load .. I think we have to use wait for this also..

Comment: sure. Add some static delay. Thread.sleep() for debugging and if that works we can take another route to wait

Comment: can you please tell what is the use of . (dot) in above locator you given before = (equal to) here.

Comment: @k00989 as I mentioned that before (dot) represent self or parent node in xpath